# Boost converter efficiency

Tags: boost, converter, efficiency

I simulated a boost converter on LTspice and have measured the steady-state output power to be 80.49 W and the average power drawn out of the input source during steady-state operation of the converter to be 84.7W. Yet when I calculate the efficiency, \$P_{out}/P_{in}\$, I get 0.95, which seems to be incorrect according to a Coursera homework assignment.

Am I missing something? Does the average power consumption of the gate driver matter?

Comment: Those figures look plausible, if quite good (quite near to 1.00). What's the actual problem?

Comment: Did you mean "watts" instead of "volts?"

Comment: @Neil_UK the converter efficiency I am inputting is being marked as incorrect, so I am wondering if the gate driver power consumption has a role in this.

Comment: @JRE yes thanks for catching that

Comment: The input power should include the power used by the gate driver.  The math is trivial, and correct.  That leaves the question of how accurate (or correct) the power measurements are.

Comment: @JRE thank you for your response, I was unaware that the gate driver power was considered an input as well.

Comment: There must be something missing from your question.  "the converter efficiency I am inputting is being marked as incorrect" -- where?  Are the values you show measured, or computed?  Computed how?  Measured how?  Who is declaring your answer incorrect?

Comment: And yes, if you're selling me a converter I don't care what proportion of the losses are burned up in the gate drivers vs. the transistors or whatever -- I only care that it's being burnt up instead of reaching the output.

Comment: @TimWescott I have now made the question more specific. Also, what exactly is being burnt up? Is it the power consumption of the gate driver.

Comment: It is still unclear if you are including the average power consumed by the gate driver in your input power.  Could you **please** include a schematic, and **details** about how you're calculating power loss.  What is being burnt up is power **in general**.  If I'm specifying or using a converter, I **do not care** if the power losses from input to output are heating up the gate driver, the transistors, the inductor's core or the inductor's wire or somewhere yet again -- I only care that it's going to heat, and not to doing the job that I want.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of the boost converter is \$P_{out}/P_{in}. P_{in} \$ is a sum of the average power drawn out of the input source during steady-state operation of the converter and the power used by the gate driver. \$P_{out}/P_{in} = 80.49 W/(84.7 W + 0.205 W) = 0.948 W/W \$ to be exact.